# xmlparser parse returns no always, how to fix?

Tags: xcode

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]   initWithString:@"..."];
NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];


//Initialize the delegate.
XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser];

//Set delegate
[xmlParser setDelegate:parser];


//Start parsing the XML file.
BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];

if(success)
    NSLog(@"No Errors");
else
    NSLog(@"Error Error Error!!!");

[xmlparser parse]
```

returns no . Why is that happening?

output: Error Error Error!!!

Comment: You have written the delegate code obtain the data, right?  Show it.

Comment: Would need to see what data you are passing to it with `initWithContentsOfURL:` (or the `url` if it is a public website).

Answer (score 1):

If you implement the `parseErrorOccurred:` method in your delegate `XMLParser` class, it will give you the exact reason for the errors.

Something like:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError {
    NSLog(@"NSXMLParser ERROR: %@ - %@", , [parseError localizedDescription], [parseError localizedFailureReason]);
}
```

Comment: :- the error is--------      NSXMLParser ERROR: The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 65.) - (null)
 what is the problem.

Comment: It probably means that the document is malformed or you've used the wrong encoding when downloading from the server so it can't be parsed.  Can you post sample xml in your question, and the encoding type?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8162477/my-nsxmlparser-is-not-parsing-and-returning-null .. here is my Question