# My NSXMLParser is not parsing and returning null

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, nsxmlparser

I was parsing my xml in some other view controller's button click but now i have changed it to the app delegate class (My app is a Universal app). so that as soon as i start my app is should parse all.My parsing methods are written in another ViewController and i am calling those methods from my appDelegate class, but it is returning me this :-

```
NSXMLParser ERROR: The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 65.) - (null)
```

dont know what i have done now. any help will be appreciable.

Comment: Could you post your XML data so we can look.

Comment: Yes i found the answer parag... actually it is a Domain error.... not in my code.. that's y i haven't given my code. Actually we have bought a new server machine so are proxies are now gone... but in my network i was still linked with proxies, so it was giving me error (NSXMLParserErrorDomain.... Well Thanks for your reply and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually as it is a **Domain error.**.. it is not on your side. you must check your internet or Proxy settings. i hope you internet must be working on simulator but not in your app.... :)

**Try it.**

Answer (score 2):

Refer the error code  `NSXMLParserSpaceRequiredError = 65` in  [NSXMLParser Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: I wish stack overflow allowed Let Me Google That For You links ;) (http://bit.ly/uikoMu)

Comment: @ deanWombourne :- SAD dude... for making fun....  but i have tried all this and you can also see the link... well i found the answer, hope you will also if you are so expert in google. :(

Comment: @ parag :- I have referred here, but nothing clearly is written here.